# Customize Google News RSS Feed

Tags: rss, google-news

I have a RSS feed of a Google News search, it looks like this:

```
https://news.google.com/news/feeds?q=Fire+Sprinklers+--flood,+--floods,+--flooding&num=50&hl=en&lr=lang_en&cr=countryUS&gbv=2&biw=1920&bih=903&um=1&scoring=n&ie=UTF-8&output=rss
```

What I want to know if it is possible to limit a Google News search to a specific locality such as a State?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is go back and add the state you want to focus on.

Say you only want news items from New York, add either "New York" or its abbreviation, "NY" as part of the search and then grab the RSS for it.

Or with the URL as you have it now, add it right after the `q=` with a plus sign, like so:

```
https://news.google.com/news/feeds?q=NY+Fire+Sprinklers+--flood,+--floods,
+--flooding&num=50&hl=en&lr=lang_en&cr=countryUS&gbv=2&biw=1920&bih=903&
um=1&scoring=n&ie=UTF-8&output=rss`
```